# workflow "action menu" popup in Oracle webcenter content(WCC aka UCM) do not show-up in correct position.

Tags: webcenter, oracle-ucm, idoc, stellent

workflow "action menu" popup in Oracle webcenter content(WCC aka UCM) on the workflow queue page do not show-up in correct position. 
When clicked on the action menu, the popup shows in front of the icon(i.e. at right position ) but when i scroll down the window and click on the action menu, it shows above its place. I have called the standard include .

I think, one way to resolve this is to override this standard include    with super i.e.   and then customizing the position of the popup.

If this is bug with WCC, then is there is any workaround rather than to go for solution above.

" style="vertical-align:middle">
            text-align:center">
                " title="" src=""   height="16" width="16" border="0" onclick="showPopup('popup__', 'actIcon_', event);">

```
        <$AllowReview=1, ShowWorkflowStepInfo=1, AllowCheckin = "", AllowCheckout = "", IsStaging=""$>
                <$if isTrue(dIsCheckedOut)$>
                    <$AllowReview=""$>
                    <$if dCheckoutUser like UserName$>
                        <$AllowCheckin=1$>
                    <$endif$>
                <$elseif not dDocTitle$>
                    <$AllowReview="", AllowCheckout=1$>
                <$elseif strIndexOf(#active.dWfStepType, ":C:") > -1$>
                    <$AllowCheckout=1$>
                <$endif$>
                <$if strEquals(#active.wfQueueActionState, "APPROVE")$>
                    <$AllowReview=""$>
                <$endif$>

                <$if AllowReview and dWfStepType and strIndexOf(dWfStepType, ":R:") < 0
                    and ((not isTrue(#env.AutoContributorAllowsReview) or 
                        strIndexOf(dWfStepType, ":CA:") < 0))$>
                    <$AllowReview=""$>
                <$endif$>
                <$if dProjectID$>
                    <$IsStaging=1$>
                <$endif$>

        <$include workflow_action_popup$>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think it is a bug, I would open an Oracle SR.

However, it might just be easiest to simply fix it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. to simply fix , you are mentioning to override the standard WorkflowInQueue component and then customize accordingly ?

Comment: I would create a new custom component. And I would use this to override whatever includes I need to.